# .NET Remoting - Proxy Problem

Tags: .net, remoting, rmi, rpc, .net-remoting

I have RemoteRamdom class on Server:

SERVER:

```
public class RemoteRandom : MarshalByRefObject
{
    Random r = new Random();

    public Random GetRandomObject()
    {
        return r;
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
        RemoteRandom remoteRandom = (RemoteRandom)Activator.GetObject(typeof(RemoteRandom), "tcp://localhost:1000/UzakNesne");
        Random r = remoteRandom.GetRandomObject();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.Next());
        }
```

**The Problem:** The client can call GetRandomObject method successfully. However, when I call the methods of r instance, it runs locally. I mean, r.Next() continues working even I close the server application.

How can r work on server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you SURE it is a remote object?

Your code basically does not show the configuration that is redirecting the Activator to actually reference the class from a server. Witbhout configuration, the activator will happily create a LOCAL CLASS.

Comment: configuration is done through .config file in the solution. I just skipped the details.

Answer (score 0):

The returned object r will be serialized and recreated locally because the Random class is marked as serializable and doesn't inherit from MarshalByRefObject.

You can create r on the server in the same way you create remoteRandom, although you'll only be able to access it from the client.